# Launch Android activity from c++ service

Tags: android, c++

I have an Android service written in c++.

I'm trying to launch another activity from this service.

I've used this command to launch it from the adb shell:
`am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.microsoft.rdc.androidx/com.microsoft.rdc.ui.activities.HomeActivity`

But when I try to run it from the code by `system()` function, I get an error:
`sh: am: inaccessible or not found`

I saw a few similar questions on the web but didn't find alternative solutions for this problem.

Any idea what can I do?
I don't use JNI on my service. Only c++ compiling by Android.mk

Comment: Random guess: `am` is not on the `$PATH` of your program, so try with the full path to `am`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I still get the error with the full path: `/system/bin/am[9]: cmd: inaccessible or not found`

Comment: The `[9]` is very probably not part of the filename.

Comment: There is no [9] in my code. this is the code I'm trying to run: `system("/system/bin/am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.microsoft.rdc.androidx/com.microsoft.rdc.ui.activities.HomeActivity");`

Comment: Please see my answer. I needed to run it from the system. anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the service ran from the vendor partition instead of the system.
When I built it for the system partition the command did work and it found the am file.